# Text and images are cut off

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

I've tried zooming out but it won't let me, the text and images are simply cut off. This also happens with code snippets sometimes.

> [image: screenshot]

WP 8.1, IE.

Comment: It would be great if you could add some info. about Windows phone model, OS, browser, etc.

Comment: What version of IE? Does it look fine if you have in portrait mode?

Comment: @Caleb whatever version of IE runs on WP 8.1; it looks fine in portrait mode.

Comment: This problem doesn't occur with Edge on Windows 10 Mobile. Either the SE devs fixed this, or it was a bug in the Trident engine.